# specific exercise about java methods and how they return data

Tags: java, parameters, return-value

I have the following problem:

Given an integer array, calculate the max value, the min value, and the average value. Write three class methods to solve this problem:

- One method where the result is obtained with the return keyword of a method in java.
- One method which returns the values interacting with some parameters.
- One method which returns the values using static type variables.

Here is my unfinished work. (I Just know how to do the first part of the exercise)

```
package anarrayproblem;
public class arreglo {
        public static int[] metodo1 (int[] arreglodeenteros)
    {
        int[] resultado =new int[3];
        resultado[0]=-1;
        resultado[1]=999;
        resultado[2]=0;
        for (int j=0; j<=2;j++)
        {
            if (arreglodeenteros[j]>resultado[0])
                resultado[0]=arreglodeenteros[j];
                if (arreglodeenteros[j]<resultado[1])
                        resultado[1]=arreglodeenteros[j];
            resultado[2]=resultado[2]+arreglodeenteros[j];
        }

        resultado[2]=(resultado[2]) /3;
        return resultado;

    }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] arreglodeenteros = {3,1,6};
        int[] resmetodo1=new int[3];
        resmetodo1=metodo1(arreglodeenteros);
        int[] resmetodo2=new int[3]; //have to write this method
            int[] resmetodo3=new int[3]; // have to write this method
        for (int i=0; i<=2;i++)
            System.out.println(resmetodo1[i]);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### method 1)

You don't need to initialize the array before calling the method, since the return value of the method is used:

```
int[] resmetodo1=metodo1(arreglodeenteros);
```

By the way: there are constants for the biggest and the smallest possible int value: 
[`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE). Consider replacing 999 and -1 with these values.

### method 2)

Your method takes some container class (or similar) as additional argument; the simplest container "class" is `int[]`:

**call**

```
int[] resmetodo2=new int[3];
method2(arreglodeenteros, resmetodo2);
// read values from resmetodo2
```

**method declaration**

```
public static void method2(int[] arreglodeenteros, final int[] results) {
     // calculations; consider reusing metodo1
     results[0] = // calculated result;
     results[1] = // calculated result;
     results[2] = // calculated result;
}
```

### method 3)

Add some static field of type `int[]` to the class `arreglo`, assign the result to this field in the method instead of returning the result and read the field from the calling method.

```
public static int[] method3result; // read from this field in main after method call
public static void method3(int[] arreglodeenteros) {
     method3result = metodo1(arreglodeenteros);
}
```

However I can see at least 2 reasons why method3 is a bad practice.